# ClassNotFoundException for applet class with java 8

Tags: java, applet

I am getting ClassNotFoundException for navigate.class when I am trying to run the below code.

The same code was working fine with java 6_45 but when I migrate my project to java 8 (or either java 7) it is not working.

I tried changing the Class name without the .class extension but it did not work.

It will be very helpful if anyone give some idea as how can it be resolved

```
<object classid="java:Navigate.class" type="application/x-java-applet" height="1000" width="150">
    <PARAM name="codebase" value="/code/applets/">
    <PARAM name="copyright" value="NetAcross Communications ltd.">
    <PARAM name="Gif-AudioSrc" value="this">
    <PARAM name="ModuleGif" value="/images/nav.gif">


<OBJECT classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0014-0002-0000-ABCDEFFEDCBA" width="150" height="1000" align="top" codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4_2-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,4,2,0">
<PARAM name="code" value="Navigate.class">
<PARAM name="codebase" value="/code/applets/">
<PARAM name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.7">
```

Comment: Can you try with the below classid? CAFEEFAC-0017-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA

Comment: Thanks @Halley, but it did not resolved the problem.

Comment: That does not appear to be [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/).  Besides that, `<PARAM name="code" value="Navigate.class">` should be `<PARAM name="code" value="Navigate">`

Comment: the above code is woking with java 6 (weblogic 8.1) but I am having trouble with java 8(weblogic 12c) .I tried removing .class also, but that dint work.